# Ruby reopen STDIN without file

Tags: ruby, io, stdin

STDIN can be reopened with File:

```
STDIN.reopen(File.open('filename'))
```

But it returns error with StringIO:

```
STDIN.reopen(StringIO.new('text'))
TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of StringIO into String
```

Should I use files for reopen always or it can be done with strings in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reassign the handle, like:

```
$stdin = StringIO.new('text')
```

Then you can work with that as you would the regular `$stdin` handle:

```
gets
# => "text"
```

It's true that the [documentation on `reopen` implies you can do this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-reopen), but for whatever reason StringIO is not derived from IO so it doesn't count as a filehandle and can't be used by that.

Comment: I try to stub user input with RSpec tests. And $stdin assigning doesn't work for it.

Comment: If you have control over the code that's doing the reading try and make a parameter for the input source so you can tweak it like this for testing purposes.

Comment: I use [HighLine gem](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) for UI. It looks to be possible to do [something](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/JEG2/highline/master/Kernel) like what you suggest. But I have not enaugh skills for that.

Comment: This is how you do it in a general sense. If you have a different question with new requirements, it's best to open up a new question to address those. Keep things focused.